# Scanning software for use with the Epson Stylus C84 Photo Edition

Tags: software-recommendation, scanner, epson

Is there a scanning program which can replace the Epson Smart Panel for use with the Epson Stylus C84 Photo Edition? I'm about to deinstall Windows XP on my laptop and would like to know if there is an alternative to Epson Smart Panel.

Comment: Please add the model of your scanner to your question.

Comment: Epson Stylus C84 Photo Edition

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you will find something equal has that is proprietary software, although you have other alternatives.

[Xsane](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xsane/)

[VueScan 9](http://www.hamrick.com./vsm.html)

Gimp also has the abbility to scan if you install the plugin QuiteInsane.

Actually i use iscan.

If you have any doubts on Scanning on Ubuntu i suggest you read the [Scanning HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo)

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-EPSON) lists scanners compatible with Linux Sane.

The Epson 1670 perfection is marked as supported. Therefore, Simple Scan, which is installed by default on Ubuntu should permit you to scan with your scanner.

However, this won't be an *exact* equivalent of Smart Panel.

Comment: I'm very sorry but I made a mistake; instead of the scanner model I wrote the inkjet printer! The scanner model is epson 1670 perfection. I know they're quite both obsolete peripherals but they're both still functioning very well. Thanks